# Basic questions about OpenStack

Tags: cloud, openstack, cloud-computing

I am asking these questions here because I could not find the answer from google.

1. Who owns the physical servers and the OpenStack software, is it the customer or Canonical?
2. Where are the physical servers hosted, are they on-premise (customer side) or off-premise (Canonical side)?
3. If the physical servers are on-premise, how does Canonical access the servers when they apply patches or do maintenance?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenStack software is open source - you can use it freely and run it on-premise or elsewhere, on your own hardware or somebody else’s.

Enterprise support is something  you can opt to pay for.

All other questions:

It probably depends on what version/flavor support combination you want to negotiate and agree with Canonical when you buy an enterprise support agreement with them.

Other vendors also offer enterprise support for OpenStack, for example Red Hat and their RedHat OpenStack platform (RHOSP)